# No values are populated in UI after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

My application contains two text boxes and one action link. On click of action link, values should be populated in text boxes. While debug I could able to see model values (name, LastName) but those are not getting populated in UI. UI showing blank fields. Please let me know why values are not getting displayed
Note: As there are several fields in model and view, I listed few here.

View:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "txtFirstName", maxlength = "30" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { id = "txtLastName", maxlength = "30" })
   @Html.ActionLink("Search", "", "", null, new { id = "btnSearch")

   $("#btnSearch").click(function (e) {
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
            var idnumber = $("#txtDocumentNo").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: $('#frm1').serialize(),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
                return false;

        });
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetDetails(User user)
 {             
        user.Name = "first name";
        user.LastName = "last name"; 

        return View("Registration", user);
 }
```

Model:

```
 public class BRUser
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: so where do you assign a value to your textboxes after an AJAX call?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to update you `UI` in the `Success` method using your `data` ... am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your ajax results in a div (UI)

```
 success: function (data) {
  $('#response').html(data);
                    }
```

And Div

```
<div id="response">Here my ajax data will be printed</div>
```

Comment: When I tried this whole page got loaded in the div. So, I used $('#divPersonalDetails').load(url2 + ' #divPersonalDetails') to load values. Values got loaded and UI showing values. But those are not getting bind with model. So, it is showing validation error messages though it has values. How to make them bind

Answer (score 0):

In the success callback of your ajax function, you need to assign the received values to your textboxes, something like this.

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function (e) {
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
            var idnumber = $("#txtDocumentNo").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: $('#frm1').serialize(),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                       $("#firstName").val(data.Name);
                       $("#lastName").val(data.LastName);
                    }
                });
                return false;

        });
```

You will need to change the ID/class of your text input boxes and values as per the format you are receiving the data in.

Comment: I tried this, but its not showing values. I kept alert(data.Name) in success: the value is undefined

Comment: As I said, you will have to change that as per your data format. Try `console.log(data)` and see the value in console. It should show the data with format if you're sending the data from server correctly.

Comment: When I see console, value of data is complete html code

Comment: So you are getting response but that's not in correct format. Check what data are you sending from server and set the format to json.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind data which received from server to UI fields for yourself. You also can google Jquery plugin to do that for you but you have to make sure data format is Json.

Comment: Can you let me know how to bind it to UI. I'm new to MVC. Please guide me

Comment: Firstly you should read about JsonResult of mvc, how do you return data to client in Json format. After that you should read docs and example about ajax on Jquery official site. Docs & example is very clear. I believe you can done this in 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Ajax you need not to return the View, J*ust return the model*...**

***Controller***

```
public User GetDetails(User _modelUser)
 {             
        _modelUser.Name = "first name";
        _modelUser.LastName = "last name";     
         return _modelUser;
 }
```

And Update in success from Jquery as

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: $('#frm1').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                           $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                           if(key=="Name")
                           $("#firstName").val(val);
                            if(key=="LastName")
                           $("#lastName").val(val);
                        })
                })
```

Comment: Changed the code as you suggested but values are not getting loaded in UI. I alert the data in success, it gave namespace of my model. when I alert data.Name, the value is undefined. :(

Comment: @lavanyab plz try again now....I have edited the code...Also is your controller being hit?

Comment: Applied the changes. controller is getting hit and values are assigned to model. still same problem. I alert the key and val after $.each line. Those are not getting populated. In console, I found "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e"

Comment: Please change the method type to post of the ajax

Comment: No luck.. Still no alert and TypeError in console. Please bear with me

Comment: Please try with removing e from the function

Comment: Removed e and my final jquery function is: $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
   var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
                var idnumber = $("#txtDocumentNo").val();
                    $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: $('#frm1').serialize(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {                        
                            alert('hi');})}});});       Still facing same problem. Its not coming inside each

Comment: I think, $.each will work only for list items. As this is model object it won't support it.